# Simple FlatBuffer over ZeroMQ C++ example - Copying struct to flatbuffer over zmq and back to a struct again

Tags: c++, sockets, struct, zeromq, flatbuffers

I've referenced some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975442/reading-flatbuffers-objects-sent-via-zmq-in-c-throws-unhandled-exception) and I'm modeling my system off of the [server](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwserver) and [client](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient) example and I feel like I'm very close.

StarBuffer.fbs:
`table StarBuffer {
    radius: double;
    mass: double;
    volume: double;
}
root_type StarBuffer;`

subscriber.cpp:

```
//    
//  Durable subscriber
//
// Olivier Chamoux <olivier.chamoux@fr.thalesgroup.com>

#include "zhelpers.hpp"
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include "StarBuffer.h" // generated flat file from StarBuffer.fbs

struct Star {
    double radius ;
    double mass;
    double volume;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    zmq::context_t context = zmq::context_t(1);

    //  Connect our subscriber socket
    zmq::socket_t subSocket = zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    subSocket.setsockopt(ZMQ_IDENTITY, "Hello", 5);
    subSocket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
    subSocket.connect("tcp://localhost:5565");

    //  Get updates, expect random Ctrl-C death
    while (1) {
        zmq::message_t receiveMessage;
        subSocket.recv(&receiveMessage);

        flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
        StarBufferBuilder builder(fbb);

        auto star = GetStarBuffer(receiveMessage.data());

        std::cout << "Received Star" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "radius: " << star->radius() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "mass: " << star->mass() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "volume: " << star->volume() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

publisher.cpp:

```
//
//  Publisher for durable subscriber
//
// Olivier Chamoux <olivier.chamoux@fr.thalesgroup.com>

#include "zhelpers.hpp"
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <random>
#include "StarBuffer.h" // generated flat file from StarBuffer.fbs

struct Star {
    double radius ;
    double mass;
    double volume;
};

template<typename Numeric, typename Generator = std::mt19937>
Numeric random(Numeric from, Numeric to)
{
    thread_local static Generator gen(std::random_device{}());

    using dist_type = typename std::conditional
    <
        std::is_integral<Numeric>::value
        , std::uniform_int_distribution<Numeric>
        , std::uniform_real_distribution<Numeric>
    >::type;

    thread_local static dist_type dist;

    return dist(gen, typename dist_type::param_type{from, to});
}


Star getRandomStar() {
    double lower_bound = 0;
    double upper_bound = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double randomRadius = random(lower_bound, upper_bound);
    double randomMass = random(lower_bound, upper_bound);
    double randomVolume = random(lower_bound, upper_bound);

    Star s = Star();
    s.radius = randomRadius;
    s.mass = randomMass;
    s.volume = randomVolume;

   return s;
}

int main () {

    zmq::context_t context = zmq::context_t(1);

    //  We send updates via this socket
    zmq::socket_t publishSocket = zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    publishSocket.bind("tcp://*:5565");

    //  Now broadcast exactly 10 updates with pause
    int update_nbr;
    for (update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 100; update_nbr++) {

        Star randomStar = getRandomStar();

        flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
        StarBufferBuilder builder(fbb);

        builder.add_radius(randomStar.radius);
        builder.add_mass(randomStar.mass);
        builder.add_volume(randomStar.volume);

        auto response = builder.Finish();
        fbb.Finish(response);

        std::cout << "Sending Star " << update_nbr << "…" << std::endl;
        int buffersize = fbb.GetSize();
        zmq::message_t request(buffersize);
        memcpy((void *)request.data(), fbb.GetBufferPointer(), buffersize);
        publishSocket.send(request);
        std::cout << "Star sent!" << std::endl;

        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The code compiles and works! I've updated the code here to reflect my working code on my local machine for people to use going forward as this took me a good amount of time to finish.

Since it took me a while to figure this stuff out too here's the build process:

`flatc --cpp StarBuffer.fbs
mv StarBuffer_generated.h StarBuffer.h
g++ -std=c++11 publisher.cpp -lzmq -o ./bin/zmq_pub
g++ -std=c++11 subscriber.cpp -lzmq -o ./bin/zmq_sub`

Requires 'zhelpers.cpp', and 'flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h' in your local directory.

Comment: Question regarding `memcpy((void *)request.data(), fbb.GetBufferPointer(), buffersize);`, - why do we need to cast it to `void *`?

Comment: I can't answer that question unfortunately - I'm not a C programmer. I hacked this together almost 2 years ago for a proof of concept that never went into production with a ton of trial and error and copy / pasting. Hopefully you can bring in a C expert to answer that question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `auto star = GetRootAsStarBuffer(request.data());`. The `Create` function you used is to create a buffer, not to read an existing one.

Unrelated, but on the writing side, you should see if you can create the `message_t` without having to use `memcpy`, which would be more efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately that function doesn't exist in my flatc generated StarBuffer.h file. All I have is two structs `StarBuffer` `StarBufferBuilder` and the static function `CreateStarBuffer`.

Comment: Add a line `root_type StarBuffer` at the end of your schema. Alternatively use the generic function `GetRoot<StarBuffer>()`.

Comment: it's compiling now thanks! I rebuilt the header file after defining a root type but now I'm getting an exception - I'll update my original post.

I'm going to revert to a different sample I think and try again. I think I hacked up this one too significantly to debug.

Comment: appreciate the help again - I've updated my post with working code after reverting back to a known-working sample.